# Can anyone explain the steps to configure mbedtls library in stm32 for https client upgrade

Tags: c

Recently i tried out configuring mbedtls in cubemx platform for stnm32f4 series as https client upgrade work. Certain related libraries like ecdha,ecdsa,ecp are creating undefined reference error.I just need the right way to configure the mbedtls in cubemx for https work.

Comment: Thia question is too broad. It is not a tutorial or teaching portal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.